# Simultaneously writing to same table with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

Developing web site (using Entity Framework) i have encountered in following questions:

1.What happens if a lot (lets say 10,000) people trying "to write" simultaneously to the same specific table in DB (SQL Server) via Entity Framework ?

2.In my project i have modules and for decoupling reasons i using singleton class (ModulesManager) which should take Action from each module and execute it asynchronous like following:

```
    public void InsertNewRecord(Action addNewRecordAction)
    {
        if (addNewRecordAction != null)
        {
            addNewRecordAction.BeginInvoke(recordCallback, null);
        }
    }
```

Is it good approach to use singleton class as only place responsible to write to DB ?

3.Does Entity Framework can provide same speed as using SQL queries  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens if a lot (lets say 10,000) people trying "to write"
>   simultaneously to the same specific table in DB (SQL Server) via
>   Entity Framework ?

If you mean inserting to the same table those insert will be processed based on transaction isolation level in the database. Usually only single transaction can hold a lock for insertion so inserts are processed in sequence (it has nothing to do with EF). Having 10.000 users concurrently inserting doesn't seem like sustainable architecture - some of them may timeout.

> In my project i have modules and for decoupling reasons i using
>   singleton class (ModulesManager) which should take Action from each
>   module and execute it asynchronous like following:

Your manager asynchronously invokes the action so the answer is mostly dependent on what the action is doing. If it opens its own context, performs some changes and saves them, you should not have any technical problem on EF side.

> Does Entity Framework can provide same speed as using SQL queries ?

No. EF does additional processing so it will always be slower.

Comment: At your opinion is it real build large scale project with using Entity Framework instead of SQL queries (the old way) ?

Comment: The scale by itself is not a constraint. The real performance requirements and the way how you design the application can require to use SQL queries directly (but not necessarily everywhere because combining EF and native SQL is still valid and sometimes even desired).